# When to stop motors in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I am a programmer for an FRC team and I had a question about when to stop motors in autonomous. I always learned that you are supposed to add a stop motors frame when using flat sequence structures. In an effort to save time I would like to know if I can have 2 frames both using the same motors for different movements without having to stop the motors in between. For example can I have our drive motors drive forward then in the next frame have the same drive motors turn right, or do I have to add a stop motors frame in between the 2?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like more of an ME question - some motors can move forward and right at the same time some can't.

If you want to execute a "move forward" and a "move right" command simultaneously simply create 2 different flat sequences with nothing connecting them and they will execute at the same time.